# Finding the best match with "fuzzy" ranking logic

Tags: sql-server

I need help with grouping results of the below temp table using a 'rank' column.

The temp table (MS SQL) is as follows:

```
student_address | school_address | student_st| school_st| district | districtID | rank 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123 some street |  12 apple way  |    CT     |   CT     |  322     |     322    |  0.2
123 some street |  33 pear street|    CT     |   NJ     |  039     |     039    |  0.1
333 another st. |      NULL      |    VT     |   NULL   |  111     |     111    |  0.0
```

I populated the @temp table as such:

```
SELECT st.student_address, sc.school_address, st.student_st, sc.district, st.districtID, '0.0' as rank
FROM students st
LEFT OUTER JOIN schools sc
ON st.[District ID] = sc.District
ORDER BY st.[District ID] asc;
```

I followed the results of my temp table by a series of updates that changed the 'rank' column based on certain rules (e.g. no match between school and student = 0.0, only a district match = 0.1, a district match & a state match = 0.2 and so on). The end result is that highly ranked rows are more likely to show the student's actual school vs. lesser ranked rows.

Where I need help is the final query. I essentially want to return all student info (all rows from the original students table) and the **most likely** corresponding school (determined by rank).

Something like (pseudo code)

```
select student_address, student_st, student_etc, school_address 
from @temp
where rank = max(rank)
group by student_address
```

I know the above isn't correct SQL, but I hope it gives you an idea what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
select student_address, student_st, student_etc, school_address,RANK
from @temp t1
group by student_address, student_st, student_etc, school_address,RANK having 
RANK=(select MAX(RANK) from @temp t2 where t1.student_address=t2.student_address)
```

Comment: Thanks, but same as my response to Jeff below.

Comment: Updated the query.@CodeSherpa

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. Probably need to use a subquery like:

```
SELECT student_address, student_st, student_etc, school_address
FROM @temp
WHERE rank = (SELECT MAX(rank) FROM @temp)
```

...though I'm missing where student_street is coming from. The above, however looks like the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. But, that just gives me results with the highest possible rank. What I want is the highest rank given the current @temp table. For example, if you look at my table, you see two options for "123 some street". In this case, return only "12 apple way" as it has a higher rank (0.2).